# "meta" in Async SQLAlchemy Example

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

In the [official SQLALchemy docs on using an async version of the traditional `Engine` API](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#synopsis-core), we are provided with the example code

```
import asyncio

from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine

async def async_main():
    engine = create_async_engine(
        "postgresql+asyncpg://scott:tiger@localhost/test", echo=True,
    )

    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(meta.drop_all)
        await conn.run_sync(meta.create_all)
```

How do we define `meta` in this example?

Answer (score 1):

Just as you normally describe `meta`: [Describing Databases with MetaData](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html?highlight=meta#module-sqlalchemy.schema).

The `run_sync` command is used to invoke special DDL functions such as MetaData.create_all() that don’t include an awaitable hook.